# Can “whose” refer to inanimate objects?

Tags: animacy, whose, relative-pronouns

I was baffled while using this sentence:

> I went into some blog site **whose** sole purpose. . . .

My question is about *whose*. Is it correct to use it there?

Comment: There are at least five duplicates found when putting the original question title in the "Ask Question" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check with a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/whose?showCookiePolicy=true) you would realize:

> **whose**
>
> of, belonging to, made by, or done by whom **or which** ⇒ whose book is lost? a song whose popularity endures

Note: When *whose* is used as a pronoun <sup>(used without a following noun)</sup> , it can only mean "that or those belonging to **whom**": *Whose is this?* <sup>(It is definitely asking whom this is belonging to)</sup>
However, when it is used as a possessive adjective, it has the definition "*of **whom or which***".

Comment: The temptation is to assume that **whose** has to have exactly the same referents as **who** can have - ie persons. The man **who** built the shed. The man **whose** shed this is. // The dog **that** lives in this kennel. The dog **whose** kennel this is. // The house **that** this man owns. The house **whose** owner is just walking towards us.

Comment: I read somewhere whose relates to alive objects

Comment: I read somewhere the moon is made of green cheese.

Comment: @user1386579 Regarding of that I've updated my answer.